# Windows 10 Pro v2004: How do I get back Taskbar behavior from earlier windows versions

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, computer-behavior

First thing: YES I searched for my problem, all I found were "Skins" or a way to get back the "Shortcut Bar" Which now ends up as a little arrow thingie on the right side of the open space which is a menu that pops up, not very useful as I could just (then) go to the start menu, what's the point? I have Classic Shell installed, it is awesome but does not customize the taskbar.

Here is the problem: On my old laptop (Windows 10 Home) I have several apps I use all the time pinned to the left end of the taskbar next to the start button. If I click an Icon, the program opens and creates a wide bar to the right of the last icon. Clicking the same icon again opens another wide bar and so on. CLicking a second icon does the same thing. I.E. if I click the explorer icon twice and google chrome icon twice, I then have four open windows on the taskbar. This is the behavior I am used to.

This does not work on my brand new Dell Laptop or my brand new Lenovo desktop, both with Windows 10 Pro v2004. On both of these PC's if you click on a pinned icon, you get one instance of the program with the icon changing to a wider bar. Now you cannot click it again to open another window. The only workaround I found works with Explorer only by adding a "/e" switch in the command line on the properties sheet.

[Old PC Desktop Screenshot - Clicked each of the applications twice, have six windows open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmGiE.jpg)

[New PC Desktop Screenshot - Chrome and Notepad were opened - Small Icons disappeared  and turned into large bars at the same location preventing opening a new instance of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRiZ6.png)

Comment: Go to Start, Settings, Personalization, Taskbar and use the option near the bottom of the right hand screen combine Taskbar buttons. I do that and my V2004 screen looks like your prior screen. I also do not have classic shell installed.

Comment: Or, if that setting is already checked (enabled), disable it so icons are not combined - whichever suits you best.

Comment: The answer given above does not work, already tried that before this post, which is the reason for the post... Note: Classic shell is installed on both pc's removing it makes no difference...

Answer (score 0):

If you hold down your shift key during icon-click you get each time a new instance.

Mario

Comment: Ok, but it still is a workaround, it is not the behavior I have on all other PC's I have used...there is something wrong somewhere and this apparently needs a Microsoft senior uber geek developer to look at it...